# Why factory is null in test form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to test my form extending `TypeTestCase` class

```
class ProjectTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{

    private $entityManager;
    private $securityContext;
    private $translator;
    private $formFactory;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        // mock any dependencies
        $this->entityManager = $this->createMock("Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface");
        $this->securityContext = $this->createMock("Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface");
        $this->translator = $this->createMock("Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface");
        $this->formFactory = $this->createMock("AppBundle\FormTemplate\Factory\FormFactory");

    }    

    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {

        $type = new ProjectType($this->entityManager,$this->securityContext, $this->translator, $this->formFactory);


        $this->factory->create($type);

    }

}
```

But, When I called `$this->factory->create($type)`, returns :

> Call to a member function create() on null

the `factory` property is null !

I'am using `Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase` and also I've used `use Symfony\Component\Form\Tests\Extension\Core\Type\TypeTestCase` and returns the same outcome.

Or, What am I doing bad ?.
Or, How do I test a Form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$this->factory` is not being initialized. That should be done by [FormIntegrationTestCase](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Test/FormIntegrationTestCase.php), which is extended by `TypeTestCase` and then by your test class.

Your `setUp()` is overriding the original `setUp()`, which initializes `$this->factory`, so you should call the parent one:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    // mock any dependencies
    $this->entityManager = $this->createMock("Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface");
    $this->securityContext = $this->createMock("Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface");
    $this->translator = $this->createMock("Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface");
    $this->formFactory = $this->createMock("AppBundle\FormTemplate\Factory\FormFactory");

}
```

Comment: `this->formFactory` is not equal to `$this->factory`